# Nodejs with Phantom-Cluster just stops

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I'm running nodejs, not as a webserver, but from the command line against a pretty heavily modified version of the example.js which comes with the phantom-cluster package.  Server is Ubuntu 13.10 in an AWS instance.

My goal is to "ping" more than 64000 urls to test for 404 or 500 http errors.  If there is an error, then log that url with the error for later processing.

Here is my code:

```
(function() {
var WEBSITES, cluster, enqueueRequests, main, phantomCluster;
var fs = require('fs');  
phantomCluster = require("./index");

cluster = require("cluster");
WEBS = [];

function loadUrls(callback)
{
    console.log("starting loaded");
    var fs = require('fs');
    var urls = [];
    fs.readFile("/home/ubuntu/phantom-cluster/theurls.txt", 'utf8', function (err, data) 
    {
        if (err) throw err;
        var myArray = data.split("\n");
        for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
        {
            urls.push(myArray[i]);
        }
        callback(null,urls);
    })
}   

enqueueRequests = function(engine) 
{
    fulfilled = 0;
    loadUrls(function(err,WEBS)
    {
        console.log(">>" + WEBS.length + " urls to process");   
        var enqueuer, i, key, _i, _results;
        enqueuer = function(request) 
        {
            var item;
            item = engine.enqueue(request);

            item.on("timeout", function() 
            {
                fs.appendFile("/home/ubuntu/error_log.log", "TIMEOUT: " + request + "\r\n", function (err) {});
            });

            return item.on("response", function() 
            {
                fulfilled++;
                console.log(fulfilled);  
            });
        };

        _results = [];
        for (i = i = 0;i < 1; i++) 
        {
            _results.push((function() 
            {
                var _results1;
                _results1 = [];
                for(x=0;x<WEBS.length;x++) 
                {
                    _results1.push(enqueuer(WEBS[x]));
                }
                return _results1;
            })());
        }
        return _results;
    });
};

main = function() 
{
    var engine;
    engine = phantomCluster.createQueued(
    {
        workers: 20,
        workerIterations: 1,
        phantomBasePort: 54321
    });
    if (cluster.isMaster) 
    {
        enqueueRequests(engine);
    } 


    engine.on("queueItemReady", function(url) 
    {
        var _this = this;
        var retVal;

        urlArray = url.split("|");
        var phantom = this.ph;
        var curPage = phantom.createPage(function(page) 
        {
            page.set('settings.loadImages', false);
            page.set('settings.javascriptEnabled', false);
            page.set('settings.resourceTimeout', 5000);
            page.set('settings.userAgent','Mozilla/5.001 (windows; U; NT4.0; en-US; rv:1.0) Gecko/25250101');
            page.set('onError', function(msg, trace) 
            {
                var msgStack = ['ERROR: ' + msg];
                if (trace && trace.length) 
                {
                    msgStack.push('TRACE:');
                    trace.forEach(function(t) 
                    {
                        msgStack.push(' -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function "' + t.function +'")' : ''));
                    });
                }
                console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
            });
            page.set('onResourceReceived', function(response) 
            {
                if((response.status == "404") || (response.status == "500")) 
                {
                    myUrl = decodeURI(response.url);
                    if(myUrl == urlArray[0])
                    {
                        retVal = response.status + "|" + url;
                        fs.appendFile("/home/ubuntu/error_log.log", response.status + "|" + url + "\r\n", function (err) {});
                        return retVal;
                    }
                }       
            });
            page.open(urlArray[0], function(status) 
            {
                _this.next(); // _this is a PhantomQueuedClusterClient object
                return _this.queueItemResponse(status);
            });
        });
    });
    return engine.start();
};

main();

}).call(this);
```

The file which is referenced as index.js is here:
https://github.com/dailymuse/phantom-cluster/blob/master/index.js
and I have not modified it at all.

This works great, and sparks up 20 worker processes which go out and get the initial response code for the queued urls.

Here is the problem:
After processing anywhere from 960-990 urls, the whole thing just stops.  no error code, no nothing.

I've tried everything I can think of from some sort of node timeout, to an issue with a given url to banging my head against my desk.  The first two would return an error when I create a test for it.  The third just makes my head hurt.

Anyone have any help or experience working with this?

**EDIT** I made an update to the code and added the on.response callback and then called the nextTick method to remove the item from the queue.  Still have the same issue.

Comment: does it change anything if you increase or reduce the number of worker processes?

Comment: It does not appear to make a difference.

Comment: I dont know what `this.ph.createPage` or `this.ph.exit` do internally, but looking at your code it seems that you just send a response back to the queue if the page was opened `return _this.queueItemResponse(status)`, I think that the processed items are not being released of the queue and it causes the engine to stop

Comment: After some more testing, there does seem to be an effect based on the number of workers (first number is urls processed, the second is the number of workers allowed):
965 - 25 - errors with "cannot read property 'getsocketname' of undefined
972 - 20
981 - 15
993 - 10
1003 - 5

Comment: So based on your suggestion, I added return     process.nextTick(function(){}); into the     return item.on("response", function() event and it has no effect.  Unless there is another way to release the items from the queue that I am not aware of (and thats a good possiblity)

Comment: I think you miss understood what I was saying, anyway I reviewed again your code before you edited it... and I think I found the issue, the `this.ph.exit()` should be inside the `page.open` function, look the example [here](http://phantomjs.org/), also get rid of the `return this.ph.createPage` and declare a variable for it like ` var curPage = this.ph.createPage`, you dont need to return values in javascript when using callback.

Comment: still ended after 975 urls.  I added the exit inside the `page.open`, created a var for the `this.ph` and have the nextTick in there as well.  Other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [link-crawler](https://github.com/dailymuse/link-crawler)? It uses phantom-cluster and prerender to do almost exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're looking to do is check HTTP status codes, you don't need a headless browser to do that.  Node can do that on it's own using [http.request()](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) or something that utilizes promises like [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise).

Unless you're needing to verify something in the rendering of the pages that you're crawling, there's no need to render the page in a browser, just make HTTP calls to the URLs and introspect their statuses.